# C# Master Detail - Data Binding

Tags: c#, linq, devexpress, master-detail, xtragrid

I have two table in the DB. One is the Projects table and the other is the Tasks table. And i have two Gridviews (shown as picture).Projects are listed on the Gridview1  and Tasks of the project are listed on the Gridview2. I want to do that When i one click to project on the Gridview1, Tasks for that project should listed in GridView2.

How can i do this ?

**NOTE: I use DevExpress and LİNQ**

[Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gn8sI.jpg)

Comment: Is there a problem you're having implementing this? It should be pretty straight forward using the way MirzaS's answer describes.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add an onclick event listener to the first grid and in the code for the event listener you need to call the query or a procedure to get all tasks for that project from db and fill the second grid with the result from that query.

I'm not aware of how your code looks like so I can't help you on that part, but this is how the logic behind it should be.

Comment: Thanks but not enough for me

Comment: It's typically enough to just use the DataMember property on the second GridControl and set it to the Tasks collection of the Projects object. Both GridControls will have the same data source; GridControl1 will have a DataMember of Projects and GridControl2 will have a DataMember of Tasks.

Comment: I did things which you said but it didn't work. Just gridcontrol1 listed projects and gridcontrol2l listed tasks of project

Answer (score 0):

I solved this question myself. I share the solution to help other people.
First of all i used RowCellClick event of Gridview1 that, means when i click the any row on the gridview1 it will bring to me what i want. So i writed this codes in the event.

```
int seciliDeger = Int32.Parse(gridViewProjeler.GetRowCellValue(e.RowHandle, "project_id").ToString());
```

In this way, I got the 'project_id'.